# Visual Studio or Eclipse - which one is better for Qt on Windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, eclipse, qt, ide

Visual Studio or Eclipse - which IDE is better for Qt on Windows?
Taking into account Eclipse is free I'm especially interested in Express version of VS but I'm open to non-free versions if this would allow much better integration with Qt.

Before posting you might take a look at similar questions on SO to **avoid** writing what I've already read :)
Looking for in-depth answers.

Comment: Is there any reason Qt Creator isn't on your list?

Comment: How is this question not subjective? You might want to state some concrete requirements, rather than simply "better integration". What does that mean to you?

Comment: This question is too subjective, there are a lot of reasons to use one or the other, beginning with the plattform for wich you are developing.

Comment: @Paul Yes, I think it won't be even close to neither VS nor Eclipse for at least 3 years from now. Let's be serious - these two IDEs have years of development behind them.

Comment: @Piotr, do you mind elaborating? I've used both VS and QtCreator extensively and while VS is a more heavy and mature IDE, I don't think that QtCreator is that bad . The fact that it's focused around Qt makes it even more appealing to Qt developing.
It might be better to point out what you're looking for specifically in your IDE.

Comment: @daniel As you've been using both you are very good candidate to compare them side by side. Write down all impressions you've got using them. Could you please? I'm sure they will be interesting and valuable.

Comment: @Greg, daniel If I knew all requirements for an IDE beforehand I wouldn't have been a simple programmer but IDE chief architect. You can't know how a cake tastes until after you try it. But you can ask other people and decide to not even taste it if it's sour and you don't like sour things. Software development is more about people than science. Ask Joel and Jeff :)

Comment: @Greg If you just can't describe what you like and what you don't about working with Qt on these two IDEs I can give you hints to start with :) 1. You can't have Qt Designer embedded in VS without paying for VS (Express version doesn't support plugins) and without paying for integration (free Qt plugin for VS doesn't do it). Can you have this for free in Eclipse? 2. Can you debug multi-threaded Qt code under Eclipse?

Comment: backslash17: "there are a lot of reasons to use one or the other" - 100% true 0% value

Comment: Piotr, no one is asking you to design an IDE, what we're merely asking is if you could point out (key) requirements for your IDE, such as: debugging, code completion, code browsing, version control integration, etc.

I think instead of trying to make other people choose the IDE for you, you should just try QtCreator (clearly you haven't) and see if you like it.

Answer (score 5):

I'll expand on my comment asking why Qt Creator isn't on your list.

I'm experienced with MSVC, and I've used Eclipse for some C++ development on Linux and been impressed with it. Despite my familiarity with these tools, I've pretty much settled on using Qt Creator for Qt based work.

Qt's signals and slots paradigm is effectively a language extension, and one that Qt Creator makes very easy to use: there's great code-completion features while writing connect() statements that intelligently display the available signals and slots on the classes you are connecting.

The help system is well integrated, the integration with the resource editor and the form designer makes it feel a little like Visual Studio too.

The debugger is adequate for most purposes, but lacks the finesse of debugging with MSVC - for some bugs I've had to drop back to using gdb manually.

The other thing I'm missing is the ability to impose some virtual organization of my code files. I can't group related classes together in the project view.

But despite those flaws, I'm loving it. Check it out!

**Edit**: improvements to both Eclipse and MSVC support are on the [Qt Roadmap](http://www.qtsoftware.com/developer/qt-roadmap#continue-and-enhance-eclipse). If Qt Creator really isn't for you, I think MSVC wins, particularly if you are already familiar with it.

Answer (score 3):

Try Qt-Creator instead. It's still in beta but getting better each version. It may not have all the features that VS and eclipse have, but it might have the ones *you* need. Plus it's very tightly integrated with Qt.

Comment: @PiedPiper See my answer to Paul Dixon's comment on my question.

Comment: I've had terrible luck with Eclipse for embedded C++ development, and mediocre results for Eclipse with native C++ development, even though it works well for Java.  Qt Creator seems to work as well as Eclipse ever did for me, but I haven't tried Eclipse in maybe 2 years (although it was billed as 'mature' at the time).