# What is the best IDE choice for GUI programming using QT4 on a windows platform?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, user-interface, ide

I am going to start developing GUI applications with QT on a Windows platform. I have Visual Studio 2008.

I would like some suggestions as to just go with the QT IDE and do everything there or just install the QT plugin for Visual Studio and keep using Visual Studio as my IDE tool.

Are there any differences or benefits? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're very experienced with Visual Studio then it's probably best to just stick with that. But the Qt IDE does have a lot of nice stuff specifically designed for working with Qt, so that would be my preference.

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked on a QT project with VS. Although I use VS for c# development.

But I have used QT creator (QT IDE) : it's fast (lighter than VS) and powerful tool except debugger VS is winner. From LGPL license and multi platform it integrates all QT supports (docs, help, nav ...) and GUI editor mode works perfectly.
I don't think you can find better in VS plugin.

Moreover QT creator interface is really simple and intuitive. You will not need to spend lots of time to assimilate it.

See [Qt: Should I use Visual Studio, Qt Creator or something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519291/qt-should-i-use-visual-studio-qt-creator-or-something-else)

See [Which is better? Qt Creator or Visual Studio IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881199/which-is-better-qt-creator-or-visual-studio-ide)

Answer (score 0):

See [Visual Studio or Eclipse - which one is better for Qt on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850477/visual-studio-or-eclipse-which-one-is-better-for-qt-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

If you can go with a slow debugger but fast & very nice IDE, then go with the Qt Creator. If you learn all the quick hotkeys (not much of them) then you'll find that you're barely using the mouse any more. I like this feature very much. You can open any file, any method or going to anywhere in your project with only keyboard very easily. Your development will be much accelerated.